# C# Mysql select Date(yyyy/mm/dd) from column by month value (12)

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to figure out the way to sum values of certain columns. How do I get Date month value from Date column where all values are in date (yyyy/mm/dd) format?

What I should write in :

```
WHERE Data = '"?????"' ";
```

I want to pick up date where month equals 12.

Here is my code :

```
MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
cnn.Open();

string query = "select sum(SUMA) from `nuolatines pajamos` WHERE ID = '" + perdavimo1.id_permetejas.ToString() + "' WHERE Data = '"+ now.Month +"' ";

MySqlCommand createCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, cnn);
var sum = createCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
nl_pajamos.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Comment: Your question is confusing, please fix it.

Comment: Do not concatenate string to form SQL queries. **Use Parameters**. You are prone to SQL Injection. As far as Date is considered from `GridView`, Parse it using `DateTime.Parse`, `DateTime.ParseExact`, there are plenty of examples here on SO.

Comment: `perdavimo1.id_permetejas.ToString()` this is bad idea. Use `perdavimo1.id_permetejas` without single quotes in SQL (ID is integer, not string). It works in your way, but is better to work with integers.

Answer (score 1):

DateTime.Parse(stringobject,cultureinfo);

for example
DateTime.Parse("20-01-2014",new CultureInfo("nl-BE